# Need to set Cells value to 1 if condition met else existing value incremented by 1 for a column in VBA-Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in `sheet1` with two columns **Name** and **Loan Amount** and a similar table in `sheet2` with an additional column called **Counter**. Example:

```
Table in Sheet1        Table in Sheet2
Name    Loan Amount    Name    Loan Amount    Counter
Ajit    8000           Ajit    8000           2
Rahul   8001           Rahul   8001           3
Gaurav  8002           Gaurav  8002           4
varun   8003           Varun   8003           2
                       Nama    30004          2
                       Sutra   30005          4
                       Patra   30006          5
                       Pakhi   30007          6
                       Ratan   30008          5
```

If `Name` in `sheet1` matches with the `Name` in `sheet2` the `Loan Amount` corresponding to the `Name` in `sheet1` should be set in `sheet2` for same `Name`. Also `Counter` should be set to 1. And if `Name` does not match in both the sheets then `Counter` in `sheet2` for those names should be incremented by 1 so that resulted table in `sheet2` look like:

```
Output Table in Sheet2
Name        Loan Amount      Counter,
Ajit            8000            1
Rahul           8001            1
Gaurav          8002            1
Varun           8003            1
Nama            30004           3
Sutra           30005           5
Patra           30006           6
Pakhi           30007           7
Ratan           30008           6
```

Please help me out with this how can I achieve this result in VBA excel. Please see what I am doing so far to achieving this but i am not getting how to increase counter where names do not match:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Count1 As Integer
Dim Count2 As Integer
Count1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Count2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To Count1
    For j = 2 To Count2
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 3).Value = 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

But through I am not getting how to increment the cells value for which names are not matching in both sheets.

Comment: Updated one you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATED :

As per your Error and Tested

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim i As Integer 's
Dim j As Integer
Dim Count1 As Integer
Dim Count2 As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Count1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Count2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To Count1

    For j = 2 To Count2
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
          Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
          Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 3).Value = 0

          Exit For
        End If

    Next j



Next i

For Each cell In Range("C2:" & "C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Let me know, if you have gotten issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Total1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Total2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
MsgBox Total1
For i = 2 To Total1
For j = 2 To Total2    
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 3).Value = 1
End If
Next j
Next i
For j = 2 To Total2
 If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> 1 Then
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 3).Value + 1
 End If
 Next j
 End Sub
```

This code is also working fine for the above solution.